# How to create arraylist of adjacent elements from another element?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So given an element of an array, I am trying to create an arraylist of Location objects that contain all elements adjacent from a given location(diagonal and next to, but not including given Location). 
Here is my location class:

```
public class Location
{
// Row and column positions.
private int row;
private int col;


public Location(int row, int col)
{
    this.row = row;
    this.col = col;

}
//getRow() & getCol() methods not shown
```

Here is the method I am trying to complete in another class:

```
public List<Location> adjacentLocations(Location location)
{
    List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<>();
    //todo, diag, next

    return locations
}
```

Comment: Provide several examples of sample input, and the output you expect for each sample input.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just specify the list as an ArrayList to begin with.
For example:

```
 ArrayList<Location> locations = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<Location> adjacentLocations(Location location)
{
    locations.add(location);
}

public ArrayList<Location> getLocations()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(locations[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that it is not valid to have negative co-ordinates.

```
public List<Location> adjacentLocations(Location location)
{
    List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();

    // Calculate all the adjacent positions relative to the specified point.
    int row = location.getRow();
    int col = location.getCol();
    for (int r = row -1; r<row +2; r++)
    {
        for (int c = col -1; c < col + 2; c++)
        {
            if ((c > -1 && r > -1) && !(r == row && c == col)) 
            {
                locations.add(new Location(r, c));
            }
        }
    }

    return locations;
}
```

Filled out class to demonstrate usage:

```
package stacktest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Location {

    // Row and column positions.
    private int row;
    private int col;

    public Location(int row, int col)
    {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;

    }

    public int getRow()
    {
        return this.row;
    }

    public int getCol()
    {
        return this.col;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "[" + row + ", " + col + "]";
    }

    public List<Location> adjacentLocations()
    {
        List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();

        // Calculate all the adjacent positions relative to the specified point.
        for (int r = row -1; r<row +2; r++)
        {
            for (int c = col -1; c < col + 2; c++)
            {
                if ((c > -1 && r > -1) && !(r == row && c == col)) 
                {
                    locations.add(new Location(r, c));
                }
            }
        }

        return locations;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Location> originalLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();
        originalLocations.add(new Location(4, 10));
        originalLocations.add(new Location(100, 100));
        originalLocations.add(new Location(1, 0));

        for (Location l: originalLocations)
        {
            List<Location> adjacent = l.adjacentLocations();
            System.out.println("orig: " + l);
            for (Location adj: adjacent)
            {
                System.out.println(" ->  " + adj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
orig: [4, 10]
 ->  [3, 9]
 ->  [3, 10]
 ->  [3, 11]
 ->  [4, 9]
 ->  [4, 11]
 ->  [5, 9]
 ->  [5, 10]
 ->  [5, 11]
orig: [100, 100]
 ->  [99, 99]
 ->  [99, 100]
 ->  [99, 101]
 ->  [100, 99]
 ->  [100, 101]
 ->  [101, 99]
 ->  [101, 100]
 ->  [101, 101]
orig: [1, 0]
 ->  [0, 0]
 ->  [0, 1]
 ->  [1, 1]
 ->  [2, 0]
 ->  [2, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks! but why does the arraylist have two null objects at the end?

Comment: @RidgeHaven I have added complete code to run the method in context and there are no nulls in the list so you may have an error somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly, you need to make list of all location elements `location[x][y]` for a given `location[i][j]` where `(x,y)` index set pair representing position belongs to the set
 `{(i-1,j-1),(i+1,j+1),(i,j+1),(i+1,j),(i-1,j),(i,j-1),(i+1,j-1),(i-1,j+1)}`